# Inconsistent Prisma performance on scaling the number of concurrent operations

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, prisma

I am running a GraphQL backend in Node.js with Apollo, and using Prisma as the ORM layer on top of Postgres. The server is running in GCP on Cloud Run, and I use a managed Postgres instance through GCP's Cloud SQL.

I am seeing very inconsistent performance with Prisma, especially in some of the more complex GraphQL resolvers which are resolving multiple database entities, and this problem gets worse as the number of concurrent queries increases. I have implemented Prisma's tracing feature with OpenTelemetry to investigate this problem, and there are 3 main issues I am running into.

### Issue 1: expensive `SELECT 1` query when waiting for connection

I am using `?connection_limit=40` in my Postgres connection string, which should leave enough connections available for Prisma. I am noticing that sometimes there are random instances of the `prisma:engine:connection` span which lasts anywhere from 700 ms to 1 sec. It is unclear why this query should take so long when most of the other queries are finishing in within 50 ms to 100 ms.

[Issue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRb9H.png)

### Issue 2: individual queries take longer as the number of concurrent queries increases

I am noticing that as I am scaling up the number of concurrent database queries within the same GraphQL query, the same individual queries take longer to finish. Generally most queries finish within 50 ms to 100 ms when there are fewer concurrent queries, but the same queries in more expensive GraphQL resolvers are running for almost 300 ms.

[Issue 2: few queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH1DL.png)

[Issue 2: more queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHRP8.png)

The Postgres instance I am using has 2 vCPUs and 8 GB memory, and I have checked all the charts on the Cloud SQL console. The CPU utilization is under 10% consistently, number of active connections peaks at ~100 whereas the limit is 400. I have also looked at some of the data in Query Insights and there is nothing that stands out in terms of query performance, so it definitely looks like this issue is happening somewhere in Prisma or how I am configuring Prisma.

### Issue 3: Prisma telemetry spans are missing

There are many `prisma:client:operation` spans that don't have anything other than a `prisma:client:serialize` child span. It is unclear why these spans are missing unless there is some DataLoader optimization happening within which is not instrumented, or that this is an issue in Prisma's tracing feature?

[Issue 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE3Z7.png)

Comment: "I am using ?connection_limit=40 in my Postgres connection string, which should leave enough connections available for Prisma"  Should maybe, but apparently doesn't. Figure out why.  Where have all the connections gone?  Look at pg_stat_activity while this thing is going on.

Comment: Concurrent queries being slower is just what I would expect.  If it is not a CPU bottleneck, it is mostly likely an IO one.  I would think "Query Insights" should make that evident, but I've never used it. EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) with track_io_timing set to on should make it evident.  Anyway, take Prisma out of the equation for testing, by extracting the underlying query and running it concurrently with some other tool (like pgbench).